# Unexpected directive 'MatSpinner' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular 5 -

here are the npm modules (package.json)-

```
   "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
```

I am using Angular material Spinner as MatSpinner Directive from Material module

```
import { MatSpinner } from "@angular/material";
@NgModule({
imports: [

MatSpinner
],
declarations: [],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
```

I am Getting an ERROR-

**Unexpected directive 'MatSpinner' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.**

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In your app-module, you would generally import MatProgressSpinnerModule, not MatSpinner.  MatSpinner would be imported in your component.

Answer (score 10):

MatSpinner & MatProgressSpinner are component and already part of **MatProgressSpinnerModule**.

In Angular,

- A component can not be added in **imports** of **@NgModule**
- A component can not be part of **declarations** of more than one **@NgModule**

> As both the components are available in **MatProgressSpinnerModule**, you should add **MatProgressSpinnerModule** in **imports** of your **@NgModule**.

### Example

```
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatProgressSpinnerModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Cause of error

> This kind of error occurs when you have to import the module but either you import wrong one or you name is incorrectly. Most of the time you import component while you have to import the Module

#### Solution

> Check your import statement and see if you have imported the correct module. Components are part of the Modules that is why you don't import component you import Module and generally, modules  have **Module** at the end of their name. Like `MatProgressSpinnerModule`